# Blazor WebAssembly InvalidCastException when running Published version on IIS

Tags: c#, iis, blazor, blazor-webassembly, .net-6.0

I have a Blazor WebAssembly application that works fine when debugging, but throws an exception when running on IIS (Published):

```
blazor.webassembly.js:1 crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Reflection.MemberAssignment.GetPropertiesIncludingInherited(Type , BindingFlags )+MoveNext()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.CreateInitializer(Type )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.PerformPropertyInjection(IServiceProvider , IComponent )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentFactory.InstantiateComponent(IServiceProvider , Type )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateComponent(Type )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.InstantiateChildComponentOnFrame(RenderTreeFrame& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewComponentFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InitializeNewSubtree(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.InsertNewFrame(DiffContext& , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.AppendDiffEntriesForRange(DiffContext& , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 , Int32 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.RenderTreeDiffBuilder.ComputeDiff(Renderer , RenderBatchBuilder , Int32 , ArrayRange`1 , ArrayRange`1 )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Rendering.ComponentState.RenderIntoBatch(RenderBatchBuilder , RenderFragment , Exception& )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.RenderInExistingBatch(RenderQueueEntry )
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.ProcessRenderQueue()
```

This error is quite useless i.m.o, as I can not find the exact cause, rather than it being an `invalid cast exception`.

Because debugging is not possible on published IIS site, I added `Console.WriteLine` to the `Program.cs` and the first `Index.razor`. However, the error occurs before the `Index.razor` is being rendered. And all code in my Program.main before the `await builder.Build().RunAsync();` call works fine as well.

So I suppose it has something to do with my `App.razor`or `MainLayout.razor`. Now the `MainLayout.razor` is located inside a Razor Class Library with namespace `Libs.Blazor.Components.Shared`.

**Program.cs**

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Program entry
  /// </summary>
  public class Program {

    /// <summary>
    /// Entry point of application
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="args">Arguments to pass</param>
    /// <returns>Task with a result</returns>
    public static async Task Main (String[] args) {
      var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
      builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
      builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

      HttpClient http = new HttpClient() {
        BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress)
      };

      IHostEnvironment hostEnvironment = new HostEnvironment() {
        ApplicationName = builder.HostEnvironment.Environment,
        EnvironmentName = builder.HostEnvironment.Environment,
        ContentRootPath = builder.HostEnvironment.Environment
      };

      builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => http);
      builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => hostEnvironment);

      using HttpResponseMessage response = await http.GetAsync("appsettings.json"); //Load the appsettings
      using Stream stream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();

      builder.Configuration.AddJsonStream(stream);
      await builder.Build().RunAsync();
    } // Main

    /// <summary>
    /// HotEnvironment filled by WebAssembly
    /// </summary>
    internal class HostEnvironment :IHostEnvironment {
      private String m_EnvironmentName;
      private String m_ApplicationName;
      private String m_ContentRootPath;
      private IFileProvider m_ContentRootFileProvider;

      /// <summary>
      /// EnvironmentName
      /// </summary>
      public String EnvironmentName { [DebuggerStepThrough()] get { return m_EnvironmentName; } set { m_EnvironmentName = value; } }

      /// <summary>
      /// ApplicationName
      /// </summary>
      public String ApplicationName { [DebuggerStepThrough()] get { return m_ApplicationName; } set { m_ApplicationName = value; } }

      /// <summary>
      /// ContentRootPath
      /// </summary>
      public String ContentRootPath { [DebuggerStepThrough()] get { return m_ContentRootPath; } set { m_ContentRootPath = value; } }

      /// <summary>
      /// FileProvider
      /// </summary>
      public IFileProvider ContentRootFileProvider { [DebuggerStepThrough()] get { return m_ContentRootFileProvider; } set { m_ContentRootFileProvider = value; } }
    } // Class HostEnvironment
  } // Class Program
```

**App.razor**

```
<Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly" AdditionalAssemblies="new[] { typeof(Libs.Blazor.Components.Shared.MainLayout).Assembly }">
  <Found Context="routeData">
    <RouteView RouteData="@routeData" DefaultLayout="@typeof(Libs.Blazor.Components.Shared.MainLayout)" />
  </Found>
  <NotFound>
    <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(Libs.Blazor.Components.Shared.MainLayout)">
      <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
    </LayoutView>
  </NotFound>
</Router>
```

**Libs.Blazor.Components.Shared.MainLayout**

```
@namespace Libs.Blazor.Components.Shared
@inherits LayoutComponentBase

<body id="LibsBody" class="LibsBody" style="cursor:default;">
  @Body
  <div id="LibsHidden"></div>
</body>
```

So I am quite confused why I get this `Invalid Cast Exception` running the application on IIS, but not when I debug it in VS.

Comment: Do you have any `@inject` or `[inject]` on the main page or on a layout?

Comment: Yes, on `Index.razor` I have these injects:

`@inject HttpClient Http`
`@inject IJSRuntime JSRuntime`
`@inject IConfiguration Configuration`
`@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager`
`@inject IHttpContextAccessor HttpContextAccessor`

Comment: And these are used inside `OnInitializedAsync()`

Comment: You wont get to OnInitizalized(), it has trouble creating your page.

Comment: I added three services to the buillder in `Program.cs`:

`builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => http);`
`builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => hostEnvironment);`
`builder.Services.AddHttpContextAccessor();`

http is created like the docs, while hostEnvironment is custom made... But its just weird that everything works fine in debug mode

Comment: You should display the complete code from your Program.cs file. Are you trying to make the HttpContext available on the browser ? No way. What do you need the HttpContext for? Commonet it out and check if the same error still persists.

Comment: The application is served inside an `<iframe>` under another application, and I need `HttpContext` to access the parent's cookies

Comment: @enet I added whole `Program.cs`. Perhaps there is something wrong with `builder.RootComponents`? I followed the new layout from.Net 6.0 though.

Comment: For cookies in a SPA, use JavaScript. But I'm not sure if you can (are allowed) to see those of the Parent.

Comment: Regarding to code exception while application run on IIS, you can use debugdiag to analyze the log file.

Comment: @BruceZhang I tried, but DebugDiag is not giving any information about the failure. Can you explain how to specifically use it for WebAssembly?

Comment: What do you mean it not give information? You need keep it running when happen, then use debugdiag analysis to analyze the dump file.

Comment: @BruceZhang I mean that it doesn't give any errors or whatsoever. I even created multiple dump files, but they all don't show the error

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By accident I solved this issue by having a look at the Publish Profiles. Somehow the target runtime was set to **Portable**, instead of the required **browser-wasm**.

[image: Target Runtime needs to be set to browser-wasm]

Comment: I also had to set **Configuration > Release - x86** to get this to work. I was fighting with this for almost 2 days now...

Comment: Is there a way to fix this in a source file somewhere? After making this change in Visual Studio, I didn't see any source file changes in git. I would like to setup the project so other team members don't need to update the Target Runtime.

It seems like it's a bug in Visual Studio that defaults the value incorrectly. The sub-menu that opens doesn't even let me pick "Portable"... but the main screen reads "Portable" until I apply/save for the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem.  The steps that worked for me to resolve were installing the .net 6 hosting bundle on the Windows Server hosting IIS.  I then rebooted the IIS server and republished my application from VS2022.  Now everything is working.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The question is unclear. The code displayed in the question is long and hard to understand

Comment: I still have the exception, even after reinstalling hosting bundle and rebooting IIS.