# Blazor WASM JWT authentication plus Google SSO

Tags: jwt, blazor, single-sign-on, openid-connect, blazor-webassembly

In my .NET 7 application I have Blazor WASM project and ASP.NET REST api protected via JWT authentication. I followed this tutorial. [Blazor WebAssembly Authentication with ASP.NET Core Identity](https://code-maze.com/blazor-webassembly-authentication-aspnetcore-identity/)

Everything is working properly. Now I would like to add another authentication via Google SSO. My plan is that Blazor client authenticate via Google. Then it gets the id_token and sends it to the backend (my API), where it verifies and returns my standard JWT token. Next, the all other API calls will be authenticated via a my JWT token. The login page looks like this:

[image]

I followed the MS documentation on [MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/standalone-with-authentication-library?view=aspnetcore-7.0&tabs=visual-studio)

Here is my Program.cs in the Blazor project:

```
var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("#app");
builder.RootComponents.Add<HeadOutlet>("head::after");

//builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://localhost:7224/") });

builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthStateProviderService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<AuthenticationStateProvider>(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<AuthStateProviderService>());

builder.Services.AddLocalization();

builder.Services.AddOidcAuthentication(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("Local", options.ProviderOptions);
});

builder.Services.AddOptions();
builder.Services.AddAuthorizationCore();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredLocalStorage();
builder.Services.AddBlazoredSessionStorage();

await builder.Build().RunAsync();
```

Here is a part of the custom AuthenticationStateProvider implementation (for JWT authentication):

```
public class AuthStateProviderService : AuthenticationStateProvider
    {
        public string? UserName { get; set; }
        public int? IDUzivatel { get; set; }

        private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
        private readonly ILocalStorageService _localStorage;

        private readonly IUzivatelService _uzivatelService;

        public AuthStateProviderService(HttpClient httpClient, ILocalStorageService localStorage, IUzivatelService uzivatelService)
        {
            _httpClient = httpClient;
            _localStorage = localStorage;
            _uzivatelService = uzivatelService;
        }

        public override async Task<AuthenticationState> GetAuthenticationStateAsync()
        {
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity();

            var token = await _localStorage.GetItemAsync<string>("authToken");

            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(token))
            {
                _httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("bearer", token);
                var claims = JwtParser.ParseClaimsFromJwt(token);
                identity = new ClaimsIdentity(claims, "jwtAuthType");

                UserName = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.NameIdentifier)?.Value ?? "";
                IDUzivatel = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "IDUzivatel")?.Value == null ? (int?)null : Convert.ToInt32(identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == "IDUzivatel")?.Value);
            }

            var principal = new ClaimsPrincipal(identity);
            var authenticationState = new AuthenticationState(principal);

            return authenticationState;
        }
...
```

Here is the Google button implementation at Login.razor:

```
<!--begin::Google link=-->
<NavLink href="authentication/login" Match="NavLinkMatch.All" class="btn btn-flex btn-outline btn-text-gray-700 btn-active-color-primary bg-state-light flex-center text-nowrap w-100">
    <img alt="Logo" src="assets/media/svg/brand-logos/google-icon.svg" class="h-15px me-3" />@Localizer["Sign in with Google"]
</NavLink>
<!--end::Google link=-->
```

Here is the Authentication.razor page:

```
@page "/authentication/{action}"
@layout LoginLayout
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication

<RemoteAuthenticatorView Action="@Action" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public string Action { get; set; }
}
```

At wwwroot/index.html I added
`<script src="_content/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication/AuthenticationService.js"></script>`

Now when I run the app and click on sign in via Google SSO I get this error:

```
crit: Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
      Unhandled exception rendering component: Specified cast is not valid.
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.WebAssemblyAuthenticationServiceCollectionExtensions.<>c__1`1[[Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationState, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Authentication, Version=7.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60]].<AddAuthenticationStateProvider>b__1_0(IServiceProvider sp)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitFactory(FactoryCallSite factoryCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor`2[[Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.RuntimeResolverContext, Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=adb9793829ddae60],[System.Object, System.Private.CoreLib, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7cec85d7bea7798e]].VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext argument)
   at Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
```

Does anyone know what the problem could be? Does anyone have a similar error? Isn't there a tutorial that solves this common scenario?

Thanks a lot

I tried googling the error but there is no answer anywhere for a similar problem

Comment: Does this solve your problem? [Blazor WebAssembly InvalidCastException when running Published version on IIS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72201074/5287638)

Comment: Unfortunately, no. I have this error already when debugging

Comment: have you got the solution. im facing same issue

Comment: Did you ever get this question answered?  I have a similar issue.